# How do I read a CSV file that is located in sharepoint website using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

```
public SharePointFileReader(String path, String login, String passwd, String domain)
{

    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(path);


    SecureString securePass = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in passwd.ToCharArray())
    {
        securePass.AppendChar(c);
    }

    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, securePass, domain);
    FileInformation sharePointFile = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, path);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You posted some code but have provided no description of what the actual problem is. Does the code work? Does it throw an error? *How* is it not working, etc. Update the question with more description, error messages, etc.